# How ng-repeat deal with scope variables of content inside it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

All:

I am new to AngularJS directive scope. I wonder if anyone could generally talk about the procedure how `ng-repeat` deals with the variable specified in the html inside it.

For example:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<body ng-controller="main">
    <div ng-repeat="d in data" ng-init="edited_odd_times=false" ng-click="editdata()">
        <span>{{d}}: {{edited_odd_times}}</span>
    </div>
</body>


<script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("main", function($scope){
        $scope.data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        $scope.data2 = [{d:1}, {d:2}, {d:3}, {d:4}];
        $scope.editdata = function(){
            // Here is my confuse, how can I access the d and edited_odd_times inside ng-repeat without putting them as paramters

        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

What I want to know is:

[1]. I wonder inside `$scope.editdata` how can I change d and edited_odd_times without putting them as paramters, or how can I access the scope generated by ng-repeat?

[2]. Why `ng-repeat` can affect the variable in the HTML inside it, while a directive( say I want to define a directive work like `ng-repeat` but only not repeat) with `scope:true` and transclude can not affect the variable in that HTML?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to pass d into editData as a parameter? That is the standard way to do this. You should also avoid using ng-init. The docs for it basically say to never use it expect for in one specific use case.

Comment: in response to [2] you can create a directive that affects the transcluded scope. Take a look at the example titled "The ways around" in this post http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

Comment: @rob  thanks, for second half of question[1], could you tell me how to access ng-repeat's scope?

Comment: You shouldn't be using ng-init. Initilise the data in the controller and then access it in the editData function. `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat` [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Answer (score 0):

## The direct answer to your quastion is below.

[1]
You should think that there is no way to access the value generated in the child scope from its parent scope.
To say in other words, the controller scope should not access the scope value generated in the directive.

[2]
You could use ngTransclude. Please check the official document again.

## I imagine what you want to achieve is like below.

In Html.

```
<div ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="testctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="d in data">
        {{d}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In controller code.

```
angular.module('testapp', [])
.controller('testctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.data = [1,2,3];
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item, i){
        if (i%2==0){
            $scope.data[i] = item + '(edited)';
        }
    });
})
```

[jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/9ty2w4ck/)

I hope this could help you. :)